# How to Switch Startup Partition without entering password

Tags: mac, startup

For testing purposes I frequently want to restart my iMac in El Capitan, Sierra, or High Sierra which I have on separate disk partitions.  When using System Preferences/Startup Disk, I have to enter my password to do that.  Is there any way to avoid this requirement?

Answer (score 2):

You can press the Alt-Key on startup to choose from the different booting devices... So you can just restart the Mac and when it "chimes" hold down the alt-key until you can see the partitions.

If you were searching another way, ask again... maybe you could turn off the password protection via System Preferences>Security>More Options>Systemwide... but I can't test it right now, I am sorry

Answer (score 1):

1. Restart and press the <kbd>Option</kbd>-Key during startup
2. Choose your Startup disk from where you want to make it as startup disk
3. Hold down the <kbd>Control</kbd>-Key the Arrow on the chosen disk turns in a Circle.
4. Click on the Circle to make this startup disk permanent.

**Note:**This Option not work on all Systems and Configurations. I've tested this with Sierra on iMac Late 2015.